# Malloc example crashing with qsort?

Tags: c, malloc, qsort

Hey I found an example of using malloc with an array of structs that fits what I'm trying to do quite well, but when I go to combine it with qsort which I need to sort by the "number" value of struct I'm not having much luck. The code complies fine with no errors but doesn't actually run and just crashes. Since I'm a beginner I have no idea what's causing the problem. If someone could shed some light on this that be brilliant thanks!

```
// Example code from "a tutorial on 'dynamic' arrays in C"
// http://fydo.net

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct DATA{
    char *name;
    int number;
} DATA;

DATA    *the_array = NULL;
int     num_elements = 0; // To keep track of the number of elements used
int     num_allocated = 0; // This is essentially how large the array is
int  compare(struct DATA *, struct DATA *);
typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);

int compare(struct DATA *elem1, struct DATA *elem2)
{
   if ( elem1->number < elem2->number)
      return -1;

   else if (elem1->number > elem2->number)
      return 1;

   else
      return 0;
}



int AddToArray (DATA item)
{
    if(num_elements == num_allocated) { // Are more refs required?

        // Feel free to change the initial number of refs and the rate at which refs are allocated.
        if (num_allocated == 0)
            num_allocated = 3; // Start off with 3 refs
        else
            num_allocated *= 2; // Double the number of refs allocated

        // Make the reallocation transactional by using a temporary variable first
        void *_tmp = realloc(the_array, (num_allocated * sizeof(DATA)));

        // If the reallocation didn't go so well, inform the user and bail out
        if (!_tmp)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Couldn't realloc memory!\n");
            return(-1);
        }

        // Things are looking good so far, so let's set the
        the_array = (DATA*)_tmp;
    }

    the_array[num_elements] = item;
    num_elements++;

    return num_elements;
}

int main()
{
    // Some data that we can play with
    char *names[6] = { "Steve", "Bill", "George", "fydo", "Dave", "Jim" };
    int numbers[6] = { 42, 33, 15, 74, 5, 20 };
    int i;

    // Populate!
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        DATA temp;

        temp.name = malloc((strlen(names[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strncpy(temp.name, names[i], strlen(names[i]) + 1);
        temp.number = numbers[i];

        if (AddToArray(temp) == -1) // If there was a problem adding to the array,
            return 1;               // we'll want to bail out of the program. You
                                    // can handle it however you wish.
    }

    //sort by number:
    qsort((void *) &the_array, 6, sizeof(struct DATA), (compfn)compare );

    // Regurgitate!
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%s's number is %d!\n", the_array[i].name, the_array[i].number);
    }

    // Deallocate!
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        free(the_array[i].name);
    }

    free(the_array);

    // All done.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger show?

Comment: Where is the crash.  Run the code though a debugger and figure our where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the array in the wrong way.

it should be

```
qsort(the_array, 6, sizeof(struct DATA), (compfn)compare );
```

[qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) expects as first argument a pointer to where the data to be sorted starts, and this is `the_array` not its address `&the_array` since you have declared it this way

```
DATA    *the_array = NULL;
```

The output would be:

```
Dave's number is 5!
George's number is 15!
Jim's number is 20!
Bill's number is 33!
Steve's number is 42!
fydo's number is 74!
```

What happens is that [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) thinks the array is starting at the address of `the_array` and start accessing other memory areas where it is not allowed to.

**EDIT**

I have tryed it with 4000 words and can't get it to crash, here is how i modified the code to read from a file, ([strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is ust handy equivalent to `malloc` + `strcpy`)

```
char name[100];
while(1 == scanf("%s", name)) {
    DATA temp;
    temp.name = strdup(name);
    temp.number = rand();
    if (AddToArray(temp) == -1) 
        return 1;               
}
```

executed like this:

```
out.exe < lorem.txt
```

The data is correctly sorted, printed and free-ed

Comment: Wow that simple! Thanks! Just a question what's the need for the (void *) in there? I noticed it works fine with or without it?

Comment: No need for it, that's why i removed it (doesn't hurt if it is there though). `void*` can point to any type of data. you can think of it as kind of generic. Since `qsort` has to work for every data type array the signature of that function needs to be done with `void*`. The same thing applies for the compare function. But to access your data you have to cast back to it.

Comment: Cheers. Probably better quickly ask here than start a new thread. I'm having a problem with my free'ing of memory using that above code when words reach a large number, it just freezes. 

    `for (i = 0; i < numberAdded; i++){
  free(the_array[i].name);
 }
` is it nessecary to free all elements or will `free(the_array);` do it for me?

Comment: what do you mean by `when words reach a large number` ? and i dont find `numberAdded` in your code, do you mean `num_elements` ?

Comment: Sorry I've changed the code a bit since posting! I have it from a txt file rather than array now. Yes I meant changing the 6 to num_elements. Well for some reason if I just write 10 odd words in array it works fine, but I just generated 2000 words of lorum ipsum and tried that and it works fine up until the free'ing memory part where it just freezes. So just thought I might have had something incorrect in that block.